# if statement ambiguity

Tags: c, compiler-construction, if-statement

I'm trying to write my own code to walk the PATH to find an executable as a learning exercise in C programming. (after sucess I might replace it with someone else's code, but for now I want to understand my mistakes).

The following section of code is not jumping to the else statement I expect ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EXECUTABLE S_IXOTH /* executable by others */
#define MAX_PATH_LEN 1024

void message (const char *msg)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "INFO: %s\n", *msg);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  char *editor;
  struct stat editor_stat;
  char full_path[MAX_PATH_LEN];
  int found_path;

  memset(full_path,0,MAX_PATH_LEN);
  strcpy(full_path,"/bin/ed");
  found_path=stat(full_path,&editor_stat);

  if (found_path!=0) {
    editor=NULL;
    message("The EDITOR specified is not found in the PATH. Using default editor");
  } else {
    if (editor_stat.st_mode&EXECUTABLE==0) {
      editor=NULL;
      message("The EDITOR specified must have world execute permission. using default editoe");
    } else {
      editor=full_path;
    }
  }

}
```

When I track it with gdb I see it jumps to the 2nd else instead of the first one, and doesn't execute the check for executable ...

```
(gdb) file /tmp/sample2
Reading symbols from /tmp/sample2...done.
(gdb) b 28
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400688: file /home/ken/c/shorter_sample.c, line 28.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/sample2 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe1f8, envp=0x7fffffffe208)
    at /home/ken/c/shorter_sample.c:28
28        if (found_path!=0) {
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.13-2.x86_64
(gdb) p found_path
$1 = 0
(gdb) s
36            editor=full_path;
(gdb)
```

it should jump to line 32 not 36.

I've tried searcing here for C ambiguity and I've read the sections from "C" by Kernighan & Ritchie that are referenced in the index under C ambiguity, and stuck as many curly braces as I can in the code but the compiler isn't doing what I intend.

FYI, I'm using gcc-4.5.1-4.fc14.x86_64 with kernel 2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64 on Fedora 14.

Comment: What is the value of editor_stat.st_mode&EXECUTABLE? Likely, it's just going through the code normally, testing the *if*, and continuing. Your code is compiled to code that doesn't correspond to the source code in a simple way the editor can always understand -- it can't track the flow perfectly, especially if you compile with optimizations of any kind.

Comment: This isn' directly relevant, but your conditional statement is more idiomatically written as an `if` ... `else if` ... `else` chain, with all 3 on the same indentation level.  I can't show the formatting in a comment.  Let me know if you'd like more explanation and I'll set up a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&` has a lower operator precedence than `==`; that means the second `if` statement is equivalent to:

```
    if (editor_stat.st_mode&(EXECUTABLE==0))
```

I'm going to go out on a limb and say `EXECUTABLE` is not `0`, which makes the `if` equivalent to:

```
    if (editor_stat.st_mode & 0)
```

or

```
    if (0)
```

The second `if` statement should be:

```
    if ((editor_stat.st_mode&EXECUTABLE)==0)
```

Comment: .. you're saying that the compiler knows that the second if statement will never be true, and hence it skips it and goes straight to the else? I think that's true. I suggest you edit your answer to clarify.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, I'm saying the second if statement is `if (val & 1)`. If `EXECUTABLE!=1`, then this is going to result in the wrong behavior.

Comment: Before helping the OP to write the correct code, could you clarify what's happening the current (incorrect) code. I think you mean `if(editor_stat.st_mode&(EXECUTABLE==0))` becomes `if(editor_stat.st_mode&0)` which becomes `if(0)`

Comment: In short, I think you've mixed up your ones and zeroes a little. It should be "I'm going to go out on a limb and say EXECUTABLE is not 0", for example.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, yes, now I see what you meant. I wrote the answer too fast.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Thanks for your help, I made the mistake of thinking bitwise & has higher precedence than equals (I know logical && is lower precedence). If the compiler decides not to code an if statement because it detects an oxymoron or tautology, shouldn't it report a warning?

Comment: @banjo67xxx, it's not required to.

Comment: @MSN I spoke to a work colleague and he suggested using the -Wall -pedantic flags to gcc, and with these flags it does give a warning: "warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ‘&’" so I'm going to use these flags every time I complile from now on.

Comment: @banjo67xxx, awesome! Glad you got something more than just this answer out of your question.